# C - Output Thread shall update when other threads modify values

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, posix, semaphore

I have a program that does some calculation by using multi threading and adds the result to a global variable. There is also a counter of how many threads have already finished and how many are still running. The threads are detached. In addition to these threads there is an output thread that recognizes if another thread changed one of these global variables. If so then it shall print them. The output thread also waits passive.

How do I make the output thread wait for changes in the global values? I could do a while loop until all threads finished and watch for changing values but that is not really what I want. I want the output thread to wait passively.

```
sem_t sem;
int val1 = 0;
int val2 = 0;
int active = 0;
int finish = 0;

void* calc(void* arg){
    sem_wait(&sem);
    calculate(arg);
    ++finish;
    sem_post(&sem);

    return NULL;
}

void* out(void* arg){

    //what to do here?

    printf();
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    pthread_t calcThread;
    int somevalue;
    sem_init(&sem, 0, argv[1]); // max amount of threads running simultaniously
    for(int i = 2; i != argc; i++){
        somevalue = atoi(argv[i]);
        pthread_create(&calcThread, NULL, calc, &somevalue))
        pthread_detach(calcThread);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's unclear to me what exactly you're asking; you've described the behavior of your program, but haven't highlighted any specific thing wrong or missing. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59667805/edit) to help make that more clear.

Comment: So what's your question? And while you're editing your question, please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'm guessing that passing the same `somevalue` to each of your threads is going to cause problems, but you haven't provided enough to code to know.

Comment: The calculations are not relevant for this problem. The problem I have is related to multi threading and how I make the output thread passively wait for changes. But I updated the question with a more precise question.

Comment: do not access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the expected number of command line parameters.  If the user did not enter the expected command line parameters, then output to `stderr` a USAGE statement, similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE" %s <list of parameters>\n", argv[0] );` followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 1):

In order to reach the behavior of passive waiting using semaphores you need 2 semaphore variables instead of one. One to control reading and one to control writing. Let's call them:

```
sem_t read, write;
```

Inside the `calc` function you need to wait for the read lock to be released. `sem_wait(&read);` and on the exit of `calc` function you need to release the write lock `sem_post(&write);` more on that later.

In the `out` function you will have the vice versa approach, you'll wait for write lock to be released `sem_wait(&write);` and at the end you'll release read lock `sem_post(&read);`

Now in the `main` you'll need to initialize both semaphores:

```
sem_init(&read, 0, 1);
sem_init(&write, 0, 0);
```

Notice that I've initialized `read` with value 1, and `write` with 0. Reason is that `sem_wait` will check the value of the semaphore, if it is greater than 0 it will decrement the value and continue processing. Since we want `calc` function to run before `out` function we initialize `read` variable with 1 so it won't wait on the first hit and just continue processing.

Whereas in the `out` function we need first values to be assigned before we can print/process them. Therefore `write` variable is initialized with 0 and it will wait until `calc` function will finish and increment `write` from 0 to 1 by calling `sem_post(&write);`

You can initialize `read` variable with the number of threads to be created but in this case race situation will occur and data might be overwritten before `out` function processes it. In order to overcome that situation you'll need to create a buffer for values such as list or array. Also an extra semaphore to control mutexlock which will be called after each `sem_wait()` and before each `sem_post()` in order not to access the value buffer at the same time.

Detailed example about semaphores can be found [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/Classes/537/Fall2008/Notes/threads-semaphores.txt):

Comment: That is not passive waiting. In this example the program checks if finish is 0 and then sleeps for 1 sec. Then it checks again and repeats it routine. But I need for the program to wait passively. Also I don't understand why the program shall sleep when finish is 0. finish counts the number of finished threads which means that if one thread finishes, its counter increases. The output thread shall continuous check if any variable of these 4 variables was modified.

Comment: If there is a solution to make a thread "passive wait" in C I'm unaware of it. I used finish since you'll need a variable to communicate between threads if you decrement finish after printing values you'd achieve some sort of mutex lock on value variables. Although declaring a boolean and using it in the if statements might be slightly more performant.

Comment: Passive waiting is something like using a semaphore (`sem_t`) to determine wether  you are allowed to perform your task. The problem with a boolean is that you cannot use it as a semaphore (not to my knowledge).

Comment: monumentally bad programming, genuinely intriguing how it is upvoted!

Comment: @iwanttocommitdie1234 updated the answer to use semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

suggest:

use a mutex or two

1. generate a `pthread_mutex_t mutexName;` that each thread uses to avoid race conditions when updating/accessing the counter and other critical data
2. the 'display' thread blocks on a `pthread_cond_t condName;` by calling: `pthread_cond_wait( condName );`.
3. each time a thread updates the counter, it then calls `pthread_cond_signal( condName )` that causes the 'display' thread to continue processing.  When the 'display' thread is finished processing, it again blocks on the 'pthread_cond'
4. strongly suggest reading: [pthread_cond](http://www.cs.kent.edu/~ruttan/sysprog/lectures/multi-thread/pthread_cond_init.html)

Note: due to various timing considerations the data being accessed should be a circular queue so no data updates get 'lost'